# Word for pretending to be ignorant in order to avoid a responsibility

Tags: single-word-requests

I once found a word I really liked, but forgot, this was a word used to describe a person who pretends not knowing or being incapable of understanding certain information in order to avoid a presumed commitment.

For example, A mother may want one of two children (A & B) to clean 'the room', so she asks child B "Has your brother (A) cleaned the room?". So the audacious child B "responds I don't know", because he assumes that if he answers "no" (which is in fact the case), then he knows that he will be told to clean it.

In short, it is basically a word that describes a person who purposefully feigns ignorance for the ulterior motive of being negligent/lazy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about *disingenuous*?

> **Disingenuous:** Not candid or sincere, typically by pretending that one knows less about something than one really does.
>
> Example: his journalist was being somewhat disingenuous as well as cynical.

— [**Lexico**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/disingenuous)

Answer (score 1):

I also forgot this word after reading it a year ago. I looked it up and I think this is what you were looking for:

**Weaponised incompetence**